# Always show datepicker in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, contact-form-7

I really need help with this.

I have a theme and a plugin that doesnt allow **the datepicker of ANY form to show when you click the field**. Since this would be very complicated to fix, searching the theme and plugin for incompatibilities, I want for the http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker/ **to always show the datepicker**, not only when you click the field.

I suppose this is pretty simple but I can't figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you download [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), upload `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.js` to your wp theme and add this script to your footer or header -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

After that, go to CF7, generate a text-field and assign the class "datepicker". You will now have a working datepicker in your contact form that works in chrome, ie, ff, and safari.
If you still want to store the selected date in some alternative input field, there is `"altField"` option with target field selector as an argument:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({altField: '#input_date'});
```

Comment: hai, actually i tried this but its not working ... any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the term “inline” in the shortcode.

```
[date inline]
```